# IntelliJ IDEA Code Folding

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-folding

I started using IntelliJ IDEA to write Java, and one thing kinda annoys me.
When I fold a one-line method, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot 1].

Is there any way to make it look like this?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: How are you folding your methods? Are you using CTRL + MINUS SIGN ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding. There is an entry 'One-line methods', which is marked by default. You can uncheck this checkbox to get rid of inconvenient code folding. There are shortcuts for folding/unfolding single method by combination `Ctrl + '-'`/`Ctrl + '+'`, or all methods in a file by combinations `Ctrl + Shift + '-'`/`Ctrl + Shift + '+'`

Answer (score 1):

Select the text when the code is "folded" and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> +  <kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Its the behavior for short one-liners
for more complex methods this will show as screenshot 2

Comment: That is not true. You can fold one liners as screenshot 2, [example](http://imgur.com/uSXEmgD)